# error when i am calling c binary from tcl script

Tags: c, linux, terminal, tcl

i have created (executable) binary "sample"   from .c  using

```
 gcc sample.c -o sample
```

it's created binary named sample sucessfully.

when i run this from terminal  like `./sample` it display a result..

but when i run this from my tcl like **`exec ./sample`** it shows error like ./sample no such file or directory..

can anyone help me to solve the above **error**?

Comment: have you tried with absolute path?

Comment: @Dipto yes i tried , but there is no use

Comment: I am not familiar with tcl much, but showing your code can get help.

Comment: Run these tcl commands: `pwd; ls` and verify you are where you think you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sample` in the *current* directory is executable, `exec ./sample` should work. Assuming that the binary itself does not generate that error message when it runs, of course. (Messages on stderr will become errors in Tcl by default.)

Check that `puts [pwd]` tells you the place you expected; if you had a `cd` elsewhere in your script then that relative path would no longer work. If this is the problem, use the *full, absolute* path to the compiled file. (You can compute this at the start of your script using `file normalize sample`, but you have to do this **before** you `cd`; good library packages do not use `cd` precisely because it is so confusing while simultaneously being usually totally unnecessary for them…)

If `file exists ./sample` is true (and `file executable ./sample` is also true, which it should be if it has just been produced by a compiler) then check *immediately after* the failed execution what the contents of the `errorInfo` and `errorCode` global variables are. They may give a bit more indication of what went wrong. (Or maybe not; can't tell for sure.)